# Insert checkbox fields in email

Tags: php, html, email, newsletter

I'm looking for a way to insert checkbox fields into an email, so when you reply the email you can send the checked fields!

Using PHP I have create an HtML email but when I reply, the checkbox fields lose values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** use forms in HTML e-mails. It's simply trimmed off from e-mail. Also, when you send a reply to an e-mail it isn't working like submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done the way you try to do it. E-mail clients are very limited in functionality and do not work the same way normal webservers do. What you should do is have the form on your server, then link to it to have the users come to your site to fill it out. The tricky part is getting the users intrested enough to actually bother to fill out your form.